# Can any injected javascript file send message to background script in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am injecting a javascript file which creates a popup form on any loaded website. Now I want to submit a request which will call a function in background.js. 
I tried sending message using chrome.runtime but background page is not able to listen to that message. 
I am injecting modal.js using background page.

The code which I am injecting into webpage to show popup (modal.js)

```
// this shows a popup form which if submitted should call a function in    background page script
$(document).ready(function () {


var modal = $('<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" role="dialog"></div>')
    .html('<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">'+
        '<div class="modal-content">'+
            '<div class="modal-header">'+
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="modal-body">'+
                '<form id="jira-form">'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                        '<select class="form-control" id="project-drop">'+
                        '</select>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</form>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="modal-footer">'+
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="btn1" >submit</button>'+
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" class="modal-close-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>');

    $(modal).appendTo('body');
    $("#modal1").modal();


$('#btn1').on('click',function(){

    // console.log(issue);
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        method: "someMethod",
        issue
    }, function(response) {

    }); 



});

});
```

The background page to handle the method call

```
var BG = {
init: function() {
     chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(a, b, c) {
        if ("someMethod" === a.method) BG.callMethod(c);
        return !0
    });

},

inject: function() {
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {
        file: "css/main.css"
    }, function() {
        if (chrome.extension.lastError) {
            chrome.extension.lastError.message;
            alert("We are sorry, but chrome reserved pages (new tab, extensions, etc) and chrome web store are not supported. Please try another page.")
        }

        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            file: "js/inject.js"
        })
    });
},

callMethod: function (data){
    alert('called');    
    $.ajax({
            url: "/someapi/url",
            type: 'POST', 
            data : JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: "json", 
            contentType: "application/json",
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);

            },
            error : function (xhr,data){
                console.log(xhr);
            }
     });
}

};
BG.init();
```

Popup.js which calls inject on browser action

```
// When the popup HTML has loaded
window.addEventListener('load', function(evt) {
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(items) {
    if(items.name && items.value){
        chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function (backgroundPage) {
            backgroundPage.BG.inject();

        });
    }
});

});
```

Here is my manifest.json :

```
{
"name": "Test",
"version": "1.0.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "test",
"background": {
    "scripts": ["js/Background.js","js/lib/jquery.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Test",
    "default_icon": "images/icon38.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"icons": {
    "16": "images/icon16.png",
    "48": "images/icon48.png",
    "128": "images/icon128.png"
},
"permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab", "<all_urls>","storage"],
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
}
```

Is this possible. If yes, how can we implement this?

Comment: Yes it's possible.  I'm having trouble understanding your code though, because you started pasting from the middle of your file.  Could you turn this into a [mcve]?

Comment: @Teepeemm please check now. I have added more code snippets

Comment: Why do you think your background script can not listen to messages sent with `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`?

Comment: @Makyen because it's not working for me. callMethod() is not getting called when I send message through chrome.runtime.sendMessage().

Comment: `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` exists specifically to send messages to scripts in the background context, including `background` scripts defined in your *manifest.json*. The only such messages which should not be received are those sent by the same script (i.e. a script does not receive the messages it, itself, sends). If you are not receiving them, then something else is wrong (e.g. not sent, listener not added correctly, etc).

Comment: FYI:  `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` is usually a bit more convenient than the `chrome.runtime` version as the ` chrome.extension` version is synchronous, not asynchronous.

Comment: You have written allot of code and made it quite complex before ensuring that the basics work. Start with the example given from Google and gradually add elements, doing regression testing all the way.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your ***manifest.json*** and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].